# How to make `unquote` output minimal quotation result in Elixir

Tags: elixir

How can I make the output of this expression

```
quote do
  defmodule X do
    unquote do
      IO.puts "working ..."
      args = [{:a, [], Elixir}, {:b, [], Elixir}]
      quote do
        def myfun(unquote_splicing(args)) do
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

which is

```
working ...
{:defmodule, [context: Elixir, import: Kernel],
 [
   {:__aliases__, [alias: false], [:X]},
   [
     do: [ # <---- WANT TO REMOVE THIS
       do: {:def, [context: Elixir, import: Kernel],
        [
          {:myfun, [context: Elixir], [{:a, [], Elixir}, {:b, [], Elixir}]},
          [do: {:__block__, [], []}]
        ]}
     ] # <---- WANT TO REMOVE THIS
   ]
 ]}
```

be exactly that of this expression

```
quote do
  defmodule X do
    def myfun(a,b) do
    end
  end
end
```

which is

```
{:defmodule, [context: Elixir, import: Kernel],
 [
   {:__aliases__, [alias: false], [:X]},
   [
     do: {:def, [context: Elixir, import: Kernel],
      [
        {:myfun, [context: Elixir], [{:a, [], Elixir}, {:b, [], Elixir}]},
        [do: {:__block__, [], []}]
      ]}
   ]
 ]}
```

?

I want to know how to modify the first expression to remove the signaled lines in its output.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is that `unquote` expects an expression, not a block.

I was trying to do too much computation inside `unquote`, hence I used `unquote do ... end`. However, in such cases we should:

- write `unquote(func(...))` and do the extensive computation in another function;
- write `unquote(data)` and do `data = func(...)` somewhere before in the code;
- or, construct the quoted expression piecemeal.

The solution to the above question was this last alternative (solution given by Fernando Tapia Rico in [Unquote leaves a trace of its own in the resulting AST #8233](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/8233)):

```
args = [{:a, [], Elixir}, {:b, [], Elixir}]

fun_ast = quote do
  def myfun(unquote_splicing(args)) do
  end
end

quote do
  defmodule X do
    unquote(fun_ast)
  end
end
```